# Decimal precision - C#

Tags: c#

All,

For a decimal value of 1 billion being retrieved from SQL Server where the associated datatype is Numeric (28,10), I am running into Conversion overflow exception. From MSDN:

> The .NET Framework decimal data type allows a maximum of 28 significant digits

I need to clarify if the digits here refer to the binary form or decimal form itself?

Comment: it refers to decimal form, number of characters, SQL allows 38 characters wheter .NET only 28

Comment: Sounds like you have a more complex problem than you'd hoped. How is the conversion being done?

Comment: @Chris: True. I thought initially it was the binary representation that caused the conversion failure. Need to dig in more now, will post my findings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limitation is imposed by the decimal representation and the 28 significant digits refer to 28 decimal digits.

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server for Numeric and Decimal datatypes this defines a maximum of 28 decimal digits (the precision) with a maximum of 10 decimal places to the right of the decimal point (the scale).

Answer (score 1):

Its Decimal digits that it will accept max of 28 digits.